# Layout for table using Bootstrap 4.2 not aligning as expected

Tags: layout, html-table, bootstrap-4

In the process of moving from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4.2. I have a table inside a Ajax modal screen. Here is the code snippet:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-hover table-responsive-lg">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center col-sm-3"><strong>ACTIVITY</strong></td>
                    <td class="text-center col-sm-3"><strong>QTY</strong></td>
                    <td class="text-center col-sm-3"><strong>RATE</strong></td>
                    <td class="text-center col-sm-3"><strong>AMOUNT</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Closing Service" CssClass="form-con"></asp:Label></td>
                    <td class="text-center ">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtClosing_QTY" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    <td class="text-center ">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtClosing_Rate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    <td class="text-center ">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtClosing_Total" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my system the columns showing QTY is too small to see the full number, even the number 1.

**UPDATE**

I changed the headers to col-sm-4 and the results are much the same. Here is an image of the outcome:

[image: Table in runtime]

**UPDATE 2**

Suggested adding ROW class to the `<tr>` results in:

[image]

Comment: What are the dimensions of your ajax modal?

Comment: Looks like need 4 columns, isn't .col-3 for 3 evenly spaced columns?  You have 4 headers.  Try col-sm-4 since you are dealing with 4 columns.  This is "breakpoint" usage format, if you play around with the bootstrap grid a little bit you should get to where you want without the autoscaling.

Comment: @brooksrelyt I'm have only the width specified at Width="572px"

Comment: Wookies is wrong. Bootstrap everything adds up to twelve if you think about it. col-3 col-3 col-3 col-3 = 12 -- 4+4+4=12 Which is three columns not 4

Comment: @brooksrelyt That is what I understood too but thought i would try everything. I posted a picture of the runtime issue I am facing...

Comment: I don't understand why ACTIVITY col is so much wider

Comment: @brooksrelyt that is my question too. This isn't the expected outcome for this table in 4.2. In 3.0 it activity was to be set wider because of the nature of the descriptions but the other columns could be adjusted to accommodate the numbers etc.

Comment: I'm trying to control the first column using css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to close this out with a solution that worked for me. It was simple to fix. In the `<thead>` section of the table I removed the col-sm-3 tag and the table behaved as expected.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `class="row"` to each `tr` instead of to the outside `div`

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 572px;">
        <div class="card-body"> 
            <div class="">
                <table class="table table-hover table-responsive-lg">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="text-center col-sm-3"><strong>ACTIVITY</strong></td>
                            <td class="text-center col-sm-3"><strong>QTY</strong></td>
                            <td class="text-center col-sm-3"><strong>RATE</strong></td>
                            <td class="text-center col-sm-3"><strong>AMOUNT</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="col-sm-3 text-center "><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Closing Service" CssClass="form-con"></asp:Label></td>
                            <td class="text-center col-sm-3">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtClosing_QTY" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox></td>
                            <td class="text-center col-sm-3">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtClosing_Rate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox></td>
                            <td class="text-center col-sm-3">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtClosing_Total" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that gave unexpected results, I posted in the original comments the picture of the results...thanks for the try though.

Comment: Hm thanks, it's hard to say because I don't see the data rendering on my side

Comment: Is there a live version to reference?

Comment: unfortunately no this is all local